# Using a form to send login info to DB

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have an HTML form set up where a user can type in their email address and a password and click submit in order to create a membership, this data is sent to a database. I looked over the code and don't see any issues but the submissions will not appear in the mySQL database.  In addition, I have been trying to redirect the user to a page once they have registered by typing in their email and password.

The form code is as follows:

```
    <form class="form-signin" action="signinprocessor.php" method="post" form name ="form1">
    <h3 class="muted">moreo</h3>
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" input name="myusername" id="myusername">
    <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" input name="mypassword" id="mypassword">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-medium btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="login">Sign in</button>
    </form>
```

Once they click submit they are taken to signinprocessor.php where the code is as follows:

```
    function createUser () {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
        {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("test", $con);

        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername'], $con);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mypassword'], $con);
        $sql = "UPDATE members SET username='$username',password='$password'";
        mysql_query( $sql , $con );

        mysql_close($con);

    }
```

Comment: 1st. mysql_ functions are depricated! Use mysqli or PDO-mysql instead !!! 
2nd. DONT SAVE PLAIN PASSWORDS !!!

Comment: have you called this function `createUser()` in `signinprocessor.php`? i don't see it is called.

Comment: did you check if the data is getting posted to signinprocessor.php

Comment: and on the basis of what are you trying to update your table ?

Comment: Yogesh: the function createUser itself is in signinprocessor.php.

Comment: nice update statement. I'm sure all your users will enjoy having the SAME username/password, since you're not filtering the update with a `WHERE` clause...

Comment: @buttonitup I knows that it is in this php file, but have you called this function using this code `createUser();`?

Comment: I did in both files and still it just takes me to an empty page, the url of which is signingprocessor.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre are just trying to create a new user so instead of using `UPDATE` use `INSERT`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO members(username,password) VALUES('$username','$password'");
```

Answer (score 1):

1) If you are creating a user, the passwords must be encrypted(hashed) like `md5()` then use an `INSERT` statement instead of update like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO members(username,password) VALUES('".$username."','".md5($password)."'");
```

2) You didn't call `createUser()` method.

**UPDATE**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

then

```
$query =  "INSERT INTO members(username,password) VALUES('".$username."','".md5($password)."'");
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

for more info visit this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php).

Comment: since mysqli and PDO are all that's left how would you convert this to mySQLI?

Answer (score 0):

Why have I been blocked from asking a question because of this post? It is most definitely in the usual question and answer yet it received 7 down votes. With the deprecation of mySQL and people being forced into PDO or mySQLI it simply is not fair that I be punished for this. I ask that you, the user, up vote me so I can use the site again. Thank you.